# Why isn't mixing a trait which does not extends super class possible?

Tags: scala, inheritance

I'm running some experiments with scala inheritance and this is what I found:

```
abstract class MixinTest {
  def test
}

trait MyTrait extends TestSuperClass{
  def get = 4
}

class TestSuperClass {
  def method = 10
}

class Concrete extends MixinTest with MyTrait{ // <---- compile error
  override def test: Unit = println("Concrete")
}
```

Error message:

> Error:(3, 39) illegal inheritance; superclass `MixinTest`  is not a
>   subclass of the superclass `TestSuperClass`  of the mixin `trait MyTrait`

It's not obvious to me why they prohibited such an inheritance? Does it have the same drawback as "classic" multiple inheritance (like in C++ for example)? Or there were some another reasons...?

Comment: The problem is that your code is trying to extend from two classes - `MixinTest` and `TestSuperClass` which is messing up the inheritance. In Scala, you can not extend form more than one class.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Nicely explained, thank you.